PowerApps: Missing dependencies when importing a solution into a new enviroment
When i am trying to import an existing solution from an enviroment into a new enviroment, i get an error saying "Missing dependencies". I am not missing objects tho. I am missing managed solutions from Microsoft. "MicrosoftPortalBase", "MicrosoftIdentity" and "MicrosoftPortalDependencies" are the solutions it's missing.
I have tried everything to find any Information about this. But i had no success so far.
I tried to import a Solution to a new enviroment to "copy" my solution holding my modeldriven App.
I want to have my modeldriven App in an enviroment where i can edit it wihtout interrupting anyone working with the app.

Had the same problem. The only way I could solve it was to install / create a Customer Portal (or Customer Self Service Portal). This can be achieved by following the steps on this page:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/supply-chain/sales-marketing/customer-portal-setup
Make sure you inactivate the site created afterwards in the Power Pages admin centre. Sites are shown on the Home page.

This happened to me because I added a field to Contacts a long time ago.
I guess the customization pulls in a bunch of dependencies that you really on
